# Jquery- retrieve HTML from an array-object of links and use RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-scraping

I'm actually trying to write a Google Chrome extension (with little-to-no experience). What I'm trying to do is this: find all people who have posted a review on an Amazon products (the links to their reviews have the word "profile" in their link attribute). Find their profiles and see if they've posted on other products by the same vendor (i.e. same author). I would then want to remove these reviewers from the main page because they might be hired by the author to publish Amazon reviews and recalibrate the Amazon rating.

I need some assistance in getting there.

First, I'm trying to get all links that have the word 'profile' in its a href tag.

I then want to retrieve the HTML of all those links and see if those webpages have the word "book" in their HTML.  How do I go about doing this?

I imagine I have to use a.get request, but I can't seem to get it right.  Something like this?

```
$('a[href*="profile"]').each(function(index) {
    $.get('$(this)', function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        }
  });
```

After a get all the HTML, how would I find whether the poster has posted on similar products?  And how would I 'recalibrate' the Amazon rating after removing biased posters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('a[href*="profile"]').each(function(index) {
    $.get(this.href, function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }
});
```

Obviously those hrefs must be pointing to pages hosted on your domain so that you don't violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction which forbids you from sending AJAX requests to pages on different domains. Be careful with this as any visitor to this site will hammer your server with as many requests as there are links containing the `profile` keyword in their `href` attribute. Could be suicidal. If on the other hand you was hoping to fetch HTML from pages that are hosted on different domains you will have to forget about javascript and AJAX and implement a server side solution.

Comment: I'm actually trying to write a Google Chrome extension (with little-to-no experience).  What I'm trying to do is this: find all people who have posted a review on an Amazon products.  Find their profiles and see if they've posted on similar products (i.e. same author).  I would then want to remove these reviewers from the main page because they might be hired by the author to publish Amazon reviews.   How would I go about doing this?